# Why do most helicopter pilots sit on the right?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, aviation-history, pilots, cockpit

A follow up on [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/why-airplane-captain-sits-on-left-seat), one answer mentioned that

> [Please note that on many helicopters, captains sit on the right side.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15148/2265)

Why is that?