# Why the pilot in command sits on the left?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, pilots, cockpit, airline-pilot

1. Is it a rule?
2. Why left?
3. I mean why the pilot in common sits on the left?
4. What is the superiority of the left side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does an airplane captain sit in the left seat?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/why-does-an-airplane-captain-sit-in-the-left-seat)

Comment: In helicopters the PiC is often on the right side.

Comment: @Arian are you talking about helicopters or airplanes?

Comment: @Farhan airplane

Comment: Airplane question has already been asked making yours a duplicate.